# A connection to the OPC .NET server fails when IXiContext.GetXiEncode() is used to construct XiUserInfo

Tags: c#, opc

I initially had an issue when trying to connect to a DeltaV OPC .NET server from a remote machine. However, the connection would fail every time and I couldn't figure out why. Here is the code that I had written:

```
public XiUserInfo Credentials(string username, string password)
{
    XiEncode rsaParamater = XiContext.GetXiEncode();
    return new XiUserInfo(RSAparamater.Encode, username, password);
}

public static void CreateContext(XiUserInfo credentials)
{
    ServiceEndpoint sep;
    sep = iEndpointDiscovery.GetServiceEndpointsByBinding("IResourceManagement", typeof(NetTcpBinding)).First();
    if (credentials != null)
    {
        iContext = XiContext.Initiate(sep, iEndpointDiscovery.ServerEntry,
                    300000, (uint)ContextOptions.EnableDataAccess,
                    (uint)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.LCID,
                    Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), credentials);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the source code for the Xi client dlls, so I took a look at the source code and was able to find out where I was going wrong. The error is in the Credentials method.

```
private XiUserInfo Credentials( string username, string password)
{
    XiEncode rsaParameter = XiContext.GetXiEncode();
    XiUserInfo xiUserInfo = new XiUserInfo( rsaParaeter.Encode, username, password );
    xiUserInfo.Id = rsaParameter.Id;
    return XiUserInfo;
}
```

XiContext.GetXiEncode() returns an instance of XiEncode which has two properties. The public RSAParameters and a GUID. However, the method also adds the private RSAParameters to a private dictionary in the XiContext class and uses the GUID as the key.

When XiUserInfo is initialized, it encrypts the username and password that are passed in with the public key. When the XiContext.Initiate method is called, in its call stack, it calls a method that decrypts the credentials but it needs that GUID from the dictionary in order to retrieve the private key. Therefore the Id property in xiUserInfo needs to be set to the Id (which has the GUID) from the XiEncode instance.